# What are the most common HTTP ports?

Tags: http

What are the most common ports for HTTP services?

80,443,8080 are common for all of us, but what else are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) Ctrl+f and search for "http," and you should find the default port for various programs' http servers, such as "GNUmp3d HTTP music streaming and Web interface" and "WebSphere Application Server HTTP Transport (port 1) default."

It's generally not good to post links as the only substantial content in answers, but there are so many default ports for various programs (some discontinued).

[SecList](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/blob/master/Discovery/Infrastructure/common-http-ports.txt) project also has a list of the most common HTTP ports